# Write a SQL to Join tables and save it to a List <Object>

Tags: java, mysql, sql, list, join

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1, glassfish 3.1, and MySQL as my DB.

I have a `List <Hotel>` object, that saves all the records from the Hotel Table (from MySQL) into it.

There is another object called `List <HotelVacancy>`, which too reads from the HotelVacancy Table from MySQL and stores the records in it.

Now what i want to do is, to get some Columns from the `Hotel` table and `HotelVacancy` table and save it in a `List <??????>` object (i have put `????` in the `list` as i am not sure what its type should be). What should be the type here ? and How do i write an SQL for this ?

Comment: Eclipse 6.9.1? You must be from the future!! Are you sure it isn't Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but this looks like a simple 1:n relation.

If that's the case, a hotel has multiple vacancies, so the HotelVacancy class then holds an instance to Hotel.

your list would then contain HotelVacancies you can get the Hotel instance then via a getter (getHotel() or something like that).

It will be a bit tricky to build such an object model just from acessing the database, that's why you would usually use a orm (object relational mapping) framework.

Common frameworks for java are: hibernate, eclipselink, or JPA

I'm sure Google will give you quite a few tutorials with these hints

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating your own class containing the columns from HotelVacancy and Hotel that you want to use and using that for the type of `List<?????>`.